# Select query - group by and sub group by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temptable]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [uid] INT NOT NULL, 
    [pid] INT NOT NULL, 
    [event] INT NOT NULL, 
    [timeStamp] DateTime NOT NULL 
)
```

I want to select count of uid (group by pid) where event = @event AND timeStamp = [MAX of timestamp](group by uid).

Note that `pid..uid` is `1..many` relationship

```
Id,uid,pid,event,timeStamp
1,20,300,100,'yesterday'
2,20,300,200,'today'
3,20,300,400,'daybefore'
4,30,300,100,'yesterday'
5,30,300,400,'daybefore'
6,40,300,100,'today'
7,40,300,200,'yesterday'
8,40,300,400,'daybefore'
```

For the above data, I should get below results if @event = 200

```
pid, count
300, 1
```

It shouldn't count uid 30 because there is no event 200 for uid 30. And it should also NOT count uid 40, because `event` for max(timestamp) i.e. `today` is 100 which doesn't match to @event i.e. 200.

`TimeStamp` is `DateTime` field but I've kept is relative in sample data for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have figured correctly, what you are after:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT pid, uid, event, timeStamp,
           maxts = MAX(timeStamp) OVER (PARTITION BY pid, uid)
    FROM tableX
  )
SELECT pid, cnt = COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE maxts = timeStamp
  AND event = 200 
GROUP BY pid ;
```

If there is a chance that you have 2 rows with identical pid, uid and timestamp, you'll need to replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT uid)`.